# python Mock "assert_has_calls" and "assert_called_once_with" nuance

Tags: python, mocking, assert

I have a `MagicMock` object called `some_magic_mock` created for a test using a a patch.

Say the patched object is `some_patched_object`.

In the code-under-test there's a call:

```
some_patched_object.some_method -= some_parameter
```

(Reminder: `-=` is actually syntactic suger for `__isub__` method)

Now, in the test code I have the following lines:

```
print some_magic_mock.mock_calls
some_magic_mock.assert_has_calls([mock.call.some_method.__isub__(some_parameter)])
some_magic_mock.some_method.__isub__.assert_called_once_with(some_parameter)
```

So what happens is the following:

1. The `print` statement prints: `[call.some_method.__isub__(some_parameter)]"`
2. The first assertion (assert_has_calls) succeeds.
3. The second assertion fails with the error message: `Expected to be called once. Called 0 times.`

I was under the impression that the assertions are equal except that the second one also asserts that `call_count` is exactly 1.

I also don't see why the second assertion fails given the `mock_calls` that I see.

In general, I feel that there's a nuance I'm missing here and will be happy to have it cleared out for me.

EDIT 1:

For those who asked:
Here is a copy paste of my code, with the actual names changed to "some_X" and "expected_X", which is basically the same thing above:

```
print self.some_magic_mock.mock_calls  
print self.some_magic_mock.some_method.__isub__.mock_calls  

self.some_magic_mock.assert_has_calls([mock.call.some_method.__isub__(expected_param)])
self.some_magic_mock.some_method.__isub__.assert_called_once_with(expected_param)
```

First print yields: `[call.some_method.__isub__(expected_param)]`
Second print yields: `[]`

First assertion passes.
Second assertion fails.

Comment: What do you get if you execute ``print some_magic_mock.some_method.mock_calls``?

Comment: If I try and subtract an integer from a mocked method I get a TypeError. Do you want to post a minimal working example of what you are doing? As you explain it I'm not sure how it works at all.

Comment: @scanny I get an empty list, as expected according to the actual behavior.

But in `print some_magic_mock.mock_calls` I clearly see: `call.some_method.__isub____(some_parameter)`

This is confusing..

Comment: @aychedee see EDIT 1 in question.